# How can I make my directive name show in VS2013 without a syntax error?

Tags: angularjs

I created a directive and I can access it like this:

```
<div id="init"
     admin-template 
     ng-show="display.init" data-template-url="init.html">
</div>
```

However VS2013 is complaining "Unknown Attribute 'admin-template'.

Why does it complain about my directive but not about 'ng-show' and all the AngularJS directives and what can I do to stop the syntax error?

Comment: visual studio maintains an xml of valid html attribute names. you would need to update that xml.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `data-*` prefixed attribute like

```
<div id="init"
     data-admin-template  
     ng-show="display.init" data-template-url="init.html">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can disable the validation of your HTML completely in VisualStudio:

`Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> HTML -> Advanced -> Validation -> Enable validation`

Or you can edit this file to "teach" VisualStudio your tags:

`C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\Packages\schemas\html\html_5.xsd`